# How to change definition of windows locale?

Tags: windows, localization

Date format of cz-CS locale has been changed in Windows Server 2016 from `d. M. yyyy` to `dd.MM.yyyy`. Users of web applications however wanted to use `d. M. yyyy` from previous Windows version, since this format is commonly used. (This format is also specified in [CLDR](https://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/35/summary/cs.html#2169).)

Where the format definition for locales is stored in Windows Server? I need to revert the Windows definition.

Note: Changing the current format in Windows does not help. It is applied to current system locale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found and used [LocaleBuilder](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41158) to change the Windows locale.